# how to plot in pandas categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I have this kind of dataframe:

```
  animal  age    where
0    dog    1   indoor
1    cat    4   indoor
2  horse    3  outdoor
```

I would like to present a bar plot in which:

y axis is age, x axis is animal, and the animals are grouped in adjacent bars with different colors.

Thanks

Comment: does it have to be pandas or can seaborn be used?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"animal":["dog","cat","horse"],"age":[1,4,3],"where":["indoor","indoor","outdoor"]})


df
animal  age where
0   dog 1   indoor
1   cat 4   indoor
2   horse   3   outdoor

ax = df.plot.bar(x="animal",y="age",color=["b","r","g"])
ax.legend("")
ax.set_ylabel("Age")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I undestand I gave a bad example.
Assume:

  animal  age    where
0    dog    1   indoor
1    cat    4   indoor
2  horse    3  outdoor
0    dog    6   outdoor
0    cat    3   indoor

Now, I want the 'animal' in x axis, but all rows for a certain animal will be grouped together in adjacent bars.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way. Set the intended x axis label as index and plot. By defaul, float/integer end up on the y axis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.set_index(df['animal']).plot( kind='bar')
plt.ylabel('age')
```

[image]